# Config file and PhoneGap

Tags: xml, cordova

I am using the following config file while using Adobe's online build service for phonegap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id          = "uk.co.0x6c77"
    versionCode = "10" 
    version     = "1.0.0" >

    <!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->

    <name>0x6C77</name>

    <description>
        0x6C77 Test
    </description>

    <author href="https://0x6C77.co.uk" email="support@0x6C77.co.uk">
        0x6C77
    </author>

    <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>

    <gap:platform name="ios" />
    <gap:platform name="android" />
    <gap:platform name="winphone" />

    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
</widget>
```

It is picking up the platform options and is only building three versions of the application, however the last two preferences don't seem to be having any effect. From what I have read the config file looks valid, could someone please confirm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was experiencing was because I had Hydration turned on. Turning off Hydration meant that most of the config options were honoured.

It still did not solve my issue with the iOS status bar style. To solve this I had to use the [StatusBar plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/304), which gave a lot more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

try ConfiGAP , it will generate config.xml for you.
 
ConfiGAP is an application designed to help you create the config.xml files used by Adobe® PhoneGap™ Build.

http://configap.com/

Comment: Thank you for the link, nice program. There are a lot more options that I realised. Unfortunately the preferences are still not being picked up. As per my original config it seems to detect the name, version, platforms etc just not the preferences :/

Answer (score 1):

Check this link : [PhoneGap config.xml file](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/config_ref_index.md.html#The%20config.xml%20File)

You need to use `preference webviewbounce=false` instead of `DisallowOverscroll`

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
```

Check this link : [here](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/disallowoverscroll_not_working_with_phonegap_build)

iOS Configuration supports following preferences :

- `<preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true"/>`
- `<preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="true"/>`
- `<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true"/>`
- `<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="local"/>`
- `<preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="white"/>`
- `<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false"/>`
- `<preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="true"/>`
- `<preference name="GapBetweenPages" value="0"/>`
- `<preference name="PageLength" value="0"/>`
- `<preference name="PaginationBreakingMode" value="page"/>`
- `<preference name="PaginationMode" value="unpaginated"/>`
- `<preference name="UIWebViewDecelerationSpeed" value="fast" />`

Android Configuration supports following preferences :

- `<preference name="KeepRunning" value="false"/>`
- `<preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="10000"/>`
- `<preference name="SplashScreen" value="mySplash"/>`
- `<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000"/>`
- `<preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="true"/>`
- `<preference name="LoadingDialog" value="My Title,My Message"/>`
- `<preference name="LoadingPageDialog" value="My Title,My Message"/>`
- `<preference name="ErrorUrl" value="myErrorPage.html"/>`
- `<preference name="ShowTitle" value="true"/>`
- `<preference name="LogLevel" value="VERBOSE"/>`

Source links:

- [iOS Configuration for Phonegap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_ios_config.md.html#iOS%20Configuration)
- [Android Configuration for Phonegap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_android_config.md.html#Android%20Configuration)
- [Additional preferences](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/2.9.0/configuring_preferences.md.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the links, I have tried `<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />` with no luck. I have also tried `<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />` to see if any preferences are picked up and it didn't appear to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Not to say that the docs are complete or 100% correct, but in the PhoneGap build documentation for preferences, it states `The following is a list of custom preferences supported by PhoneGap Build.` and both of the preferences you are trying to set are not listed.

[Preference Docs](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_preferences.md.html#Preferences)

Update*

some people are saying to try `webviewbounce=false` in place of `DisallowOverscroll=true`

Also, another possible work around could be using the native settings via `<gap:config-file platform="" parent="" overwrite="" />`

Here are the docs for that : http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_config_file_element.md.html#Config%20File%20Elements

Comment: I had missed that link and had assumed build would have the same preferences as PhoneGap. After following that link I tried adding:
`<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />`
But it doesn't seem to have any effect either. I am wondering if I am putting the preferences in the correct place.

Comment: which device(s) or emulator(s) are you testing with?

Comment: I am using an iPhone 4 (iOS 7) and an Android 4.1.2 (Samsung S3 mini)

Comment: Reading the docs again, one thing I noticed missing is `xmlns:android   = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`. It needs to go in the initial widget definition for android settings to take. but that shouldn't affect ios. Your config looks correct other than the android namespace needing to be added.